# Linear Transformation such that Image(T) = V

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to solve this problem:
**Let T:V → V  be a linear transformation such that Image(T)=V. If  v<sub>1</sub>,  v<sub>1</sub>...v<sub>n</sub> spans V show that T(v<sub>1</sub>), T(v<sub>2</sub>),...T(v<sub>n</sub>) also spans V.**

My intuition is that because the image of T=V that the range of values in the mapping of V to V must only be mappable from the original set to itself. This would imply the sets would have to be identical, and thus the post transformation it would also span V. I feel like I'm wrong though.

Comment: False as written. Do you mean to add that the set $\{v_i\}$ spans $V$? If so, then write a linear combination of those vectors and apply $T$, then abuse linearity.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v$ an arbitrary vector on $\textsf{V}$. We *want to show* that $v$ is a linear combination of the vectors $\textsf{T}(v_1),\textsf{T}(v_2),\dots,\textsf{T}(v_n)$.

But, since the image of $\textsf{T}$ is the whole space, $v$ must be in the image of $\textsf{T}$, that is, $v=\textsf{T}(u)$ for some vector $u$ in $\textsf{V}$. Since the $v_i$'s spans $\textsf{V}$, and $u$ is in $\textsf{V}$, write
$$u=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i \quad \textrm{for some scalars } a_1,\dots,a_n$$
So,
$$v=\textsf{T}(u)=\textsf{T}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\textsf{T}(v_i)$$
as we want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "if $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ span $V$ then $\{T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_n)\}$ span $V$.

Well, for $\{T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_n)\}$ to span $V$ means that any vector $w$ can be written as a non-trivial linear combination of them. By assumption, since the image of $T$ is the whole space, there is some vector $v$ such that $T(v)=w$. Also, since $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ span $V$, write, express $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots c_nv_n$. Then the map $T$ on $v$ by linearity is $T(v)=w=c_1T(v_1)+\cdots c_nT(v_n)$. This is what we wanted to show.